Using <select></select> to Show Name + Surname and value = "id"
I tried to show all users with role "Trainer" and choose one of them. But post an id.
select returns null.
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="TrainerId">Тренер</label>
        <select asp-for="TrainerId" class="form-control" asp-items="@ViewBag.TrainerList">
            <option>Выберите тренера</option>
        </select>
    </div>

public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
{
    var trainersFromRole = await _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync(UserRoles.Trainer);
    var trainers = trainersFromRole.Select(t => new
    {
        Id = t.Id,
        FullName = $"{t.Name} {t.Surname}"
    }).ToList();

    var selectedList = new SelectList(trainers, "Id", "FullName");
    ViewBag.TrainerList = selectedList;
    return View();
}

    public class AppUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string BirthDay { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Course>? Courses { get; set; }
    }

Course Model (I try to fill TrainerId)
    public class Course
    {
        [Key]
        public int CourseId { get; set ;}
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string DayStart { get; set; }
        public string MonthStart { get; set; }
        public string TimeStart { get; set; }
        public string TimeEnd { get; set; }
        public string TrainerId { get; set; }
    }

I tried many ways and select returned null

You mean the drop down list is empty when selecting trainer? You can check whether the trainers queried in the create method are empty by setting a breakpoint. And whether to specify the model type in the view like @model Course. Or is it that after selecting a Trainer in select, I receive empty data after submitting it to the server? If so, can you describe your post method? You can view the network request by using the browser's developer tools to check whether the passed data contains the Id, and by setting breakpoints to check whether the server successfully received the passed data.

I forgot {get; (set)} in my ViewModel....
